# Can I use biicode for C++ on ubuntu 14.04 with Cmake 2.8.12.2?

Tags: c++, cmake, biicode

I just downloaded biicode and tried to follow the [getting started instructions](http://docs.biicode.com/c++/gettingstarted.html) but received an error about the Cmake 3.0 or higher being required.

However, [ubuntu 14.4 uses](https://launchpad.net/cmake/+packages) "cmake version 2.8.12.2"

Is there a way to use biicode with 2.8 or am I stuck installing the newer version of CMake?

TIA!

Comment: Did you try removing the "required minimum version" from the CMakeLists.txt? It _might_ work, but usually, this information has its meaning.

Comment: With most build tools I got the experience that if some program requires particular version of it, it usually make use of some feature available from that version and eventually upgrading toolchains requires less effort than modifying build scripts to run on the one I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, biicode requires cmake > 3.0. There is a setup command that helps installing it:

```
$ bii setup:cpp
```

This will install CMake >3.0 in /home/user/biicode_env, and add it to the path, so it doesnt interfere/overwrite your current 2.8 installation. Biicode needs that executing "cmake" in the console actually uses 3.0, so it should be first in the path. You can manage it very easily in two different ways, with a symbolic link (/usr/bin) that you redirect as needed or adding/removing an entry in the path before executing biicode.

This is a different thing, but I woiuld like to say that I have migrated existing projects from cmake 2.8 to 3.0 without any problems, and 3.0 runs great and has useful new features. So I would recommend regular cmake users to upgrade if possible.

Comment: I had to update following the instructions here http://docs.biicode.com/c++/installation.html#alternative-install-debian and then everything started working in the Getting started tutorial http://docs.biicode.com/c++/gettingstarted.html

Comment: Oh, did I mention that I also downloaded CMake 3.0.2 and put it's bin on my PATH before the normal PATH contents? That was critical to solving the problem too!

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't any way to change this requirement because internal biicode CMake has features, like the use of INTERFACE libraries, which are only available on CMake 3.0 or later. However, don't worry about upgrading CMake version, this one always keeps a exhaustive compatibility with older versions ;)